# Passing route functions to HTML via Socket.io Websocket

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Heyo.

i have an websocket defined like this.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = new Server(server, {
cors: {
    origin: "*",
    method: ["GET", "POST", "PUT"],
  },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
 console.log(`user connected: ${socket.id}`);
});

server.listen(3001, () => {
console.log("websocket online");
});
```

The following code is the function i want to pass to my frontend html via websocket, which is accessed by pressing an button on my frontend html.

```
app.get("/updateSomething", (req,res) {
//some code
}
```

My question would be: How do i tell my frontend to access that specific function from my node script via button click.

```
<button>DoSomething</button>
```

Comment: What do you mean by different functions for path? Can you be more clear. Looks like you already know how to write methods that run when a route is hit and return the response, so what are we looking for

Comment: i want to define diffrent routes on my websocket so i can access the functions from my html but i cant make them work when i simply add app.get with the params in the websocket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to emit to your socket.io server when you press that button.

For example in your client html:

```
<button id="doSomethingBtn">DoSomething</button>
<script>
const socket = io();

document.getElementById("doSomethingBtn").addEventListener("click", () => {
    socket.emit("buttonClicked", 'someData');
});
</script>
```

and in your server handle this emit

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
 console.log(`user connected: ${socket.id}`);

 socket.on("buttonClicked", (someData) => {
   console.log("button Clicked!")
   // here you can do any code you want including running whatever is in your app.get
 });
});
```

Please dont hesitate to make a comment if you dont understand soemthing or you need more help.

Comment: so for any route i have i just create an `socket.on("name", (data) => {//code})`. And i can pass whatever i want in that part of the code right. For example an api call to Rest Api. For the Handling the Data part do i do that in the same route or what would be the best practice for that?

Comment: If you want to call a rest API then you won't need socket.io? You can just directly do that using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: the websocket part comes in to have an continuous connection for displayinig the data in real time. I want to make an site, where i can display the data in realtime on other clients.

Comment: Yes, using `emit` and `.on`, you can send and download data realtime using socket.io. I just don't understand the part about the rest API. Are you trying to do that from the server (to another server)? Or should your client connect to an Api route in YOUR server.

Comment: Im fetching data from the REST api and displaying it via socket on my frontend. I tried it with axios normal http requests but i couldnt make the Site showing data async. Someone on here recommended me the use of websockets. Thats why i started doing it with that technique. Client connects to websocket. websocket fetches and sends data back continuously! :D

Comment: So the server does a request to a REST api and it should be sent continuosly to the client via websocket? If that is the case you might have to do it a bit differently, emitting from the server once the request has been made.

Comment: oh okay. what would be the best practice for that. im always open for recommendations especially when my approach is not correct. thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know if this would be the best for your need, but you could use a `setInterval` doing the API request on the server, and once it has completed, use `io.emit` to emit to all sockets with the data, and on your client use `socket.on` to get that data and use it however you wish. T